# Check sort order in drop down - advice for best approach using selenium/java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, pageobjects

I have a drop down where I should check whether the items in it are sorted alphabetically.

Right now I use two methods that does that job.

I see a couple of drawbacks in this way:

1. The code looks lengthy
2. I have to do the same step in every page (I use PabeObject model) instead of just using it in BasePage and calling it in other pages.

I need advice on whether is there any better way to handle this?

My code:

```
List<WebElement> issurTypeDropdown =new LinkedList<>(driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//INPUT[@type='search'])[4]/following-sibling::UL")));
        LinkedList<String> issueTypes =new LinkedList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i< issurTypeDropdown.size(); i++)
        {

//            System.out.println(issurTypeDropdown.get(i).getText());
            issueTypes.add(issurTypeDropdown.get(i).getText());
        }
        boolean result = comp_order(issueTypes);

        return new add_issue_page();
    }

    //to compare
    public static boolean comp_order(LinkedList<String> pn)
    {
        String prev=""; // empty string
        for (final String cur: pn)
        {
            if (cur.compareTo(prev) < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            prev=cur;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I use to verify if array is sorted alphabetically. `Ordering` is part of [Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava) library that is developed by Google.

```
public boolean isArraySortedAlphabetically(ArrayList<String> list){
    boolean isSorted = Ordering.from(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).isOrdered(list);
    return isSorted;
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you store the dropdown values?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was able to do this by making it as method that cna be used anywhere in your pages once it is moved to BasePage:

```
  protected boolean CheckSorting(String xpathExpression) {
        List<WebElement> issueTypeDropdown = new LinkedList<>(driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression)));
        LinkedList<String> issueTypes = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < issueTypeDropdown.size(); i++) {
//            System.out.println(issueTypeDropdown.get(i).getText());
            issueTypes.add(issueTypeDropdown.get(i).getText());
        }
        return Compare(issueTypes);
    }
```